# Using Google Charts with an HTML <form> to create a graph

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, google-visualization

Lately i am trying to insert Visual Analytics on a project ive been working on, and i would like to have the ability to create a graph from a UI that is in an HTML `form`. The code of my HTML page is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

  <title>Charts</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS CDN -->
  
  <!-- Our Custom CSS -->
  <!-- Font Awesome JS -->
  <!--Load the AJAX --> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <!-- Sidebar  -->
    <nav id="sidebar">
    // standard sidebar stuff
    </nav>

    <!-- Page Content  -->
    <div id="content">

      <form action="getData.php" method="POST" id="form">
        <table class="" id="chart-searching">

          <tr id="type_of_chart_row">
            
            <th>Type of Chart</th>
            <td colspan="3" class="">
              <select id="type_of_chart" name="charts">
                <option value="Pie_chart">Pie chart</option> 
                <option value="Bar_chart">Bar chart</option> 
                <option value="Col_chart">Column chart</option> 
                <option value="Area_chart">Area</option>
                <option value="Line_chart">Line chart</option>
                
              </select>
            </td>
          
            <th>Select an Attribute</th>

            <td colspan="3" id="attribute_row">
              <select id="attributes" name="attributes">
                <option value="Patient_name">Name</option>
                <option value="Patient_id">ID</option>
                <option value="Sex">Sex</option>
                <option value="Race">Race</option>
                <option value="Age">Age</option>
                <option value="Comorbidities">Comorbidities</option>
                <option value="Email">Email</option>
                <option value="eddsscore">EDSS Score</option>
                <option value="Phonenum">Phone Number</option>
                <option value="onsetsymptoms">Onset Symptoms</option>
                <option value="Onsetlocalisation">Onset Localisation</option>
                <option value="smoker">Smoker</option>
                <option value="Pregnant">Pregnant</option>
                <option value="MRIenhancing">MRI Enhanced Lesions</option>
                <option value="MRInum">MRI Enhanced Lesions Number</option>
                <option value="MRIonsetlocalisation">MRI Onset Localisation</option>
              </select>
            </td>

          </tr>
        </table>

        <button type="submit" name="makeGraph" value="Create Graph" id="test" onclick="">Create Graph</button>
      
      </form>
      
      
      <div id="chart_div"></div>

    </div>
  </div>
      
  <!-- Popper.JS -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  
  <script type="text/javascript">//sidebarCollapse
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#sidebarCollapse').on('click', function() {
        $('#sidebar').toggleClass('active');
      });
    });
  </script>  
</body>
</html>
```

The file that handles the form is the `getData.php`

```
<?php
session_start();
error_reporting(0);
if (isset($_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY']) && (time() - $_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] > 18000)) {
  // last request was more than 30 minutes ago
  session_unset();     // unset $_SESSION variable for the run-time
  session_destroy();   // destroy session data in storage
  $scripttimedout = file_get_contents('timeout.js');
  echo "<script>" . $scripttimedout . "</script>";
} 
$_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] = time(); // update last activity time stamp?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>charts</title>
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS CDN -->
  <!-- Our Custom CSS -->
  <!-- Font Awesome JS -->
    <!--Load AJAX-->
    <script src="/MSR/application/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});</script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      // Load the Visualization API and the corechart package.
      // google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});

      // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
      // instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
      // draws it.
      function drawChart() {

        // Create the data table.
        var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            
            ['Patient_name','number'],
            <?php 
              $sql = "SELECT Patient_name, count(*) as number FROM patients JOIN MSR ON patients.Patient_id = MSR.NDSnum WHERE Doctor_ID = '$usersid' GROUP BY Patient_name";
              $result = $pdo->query($sql);
              $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
              while($row = $result->fetch()){
                // $array[] = $row;
                  echo "['".$row['Patient_name']."',".$row['number']."],";
              }
            ?>
        ]);
        // data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
        // data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
        // data.addRows([
        //   ['Mushrooms', 3],
        //   ['Onions', 1],
        //   ['Olives', 1],
        //   ['Zucchini', 1],
        //   ['Pepperoni', 2]
        // ]);
        // Set chart options
        var options = {'title':'How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night',
                       'width':400,
                       'height':300};

        // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <!-- Sidebar  -->
    <nav id="sidebar">
    </nav>

    <!-- Page Content  -->
    <div id="content">
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto">
              <li class="navbar-nav">
                <a class="nav-link" id="">
                  <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
                  Doctor: <u><?php $user_name = $_SESSION['user'];
                                    
                              echo $user_name.$usersid; ?></u>
                </a>
                <a href="logout.php" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to logout?');">
                  <button type="button" id="logoutBtn" class="navbar-btn btn btn-info">
                    <!-- <i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i> -->
                    <span>Logout</span>
                  </button>
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>

        <div id="chart_div"></div>

      <footer>
      </footer>
    </div>
  </div>
     
  <!-- Popper.JS -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  
  <script type="text/javascript">//sidebarCollapse
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#sidebarCollapse').on('click', function() {
        $('#sidebar').toggleClass('active');
      });
    });
  </script>
     
</body>

</html>

<?php

    //database connection info (this part works fine)
            
      $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
      // set the PDO error mode to exception
      $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);


    // get data from the form
        $createGraph = $_POST['makeGraph'];
        $attributes = $_POST['attributes'];
        $charts = $_POST['charts'];

        if (isset($_POST['makeGraph'])) {
          try {
              $array = array();
              if ($charts == 'Pie_chart'){
                  if($attributes == 'Patient_name'){
                      $sql = "SELECT Patient_name, count(*) as number 
                      FROM patients JOIN MSR ON patients.Patient_id = MSR.NDSnum 
                      WHERE Doctor_ID = '$usersid' GROUP BY Patient_name";
                      $result = $pdo->query($sql);
                      $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                      while($row = $result->fetch()){
                        $array[] = $row;
                      }
                      $jsonArray = json_encode($array,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
                      echo $jsonArray;  
                  }
             // hoping to make something similar in the if statements with the rest of the attributes (email-sex-Race etc...)
              
          } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo"<div class='error'>";
              echo $statement . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
              die("ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . $e->getMessage());
            echo "</div>";
          }
        }
?>
```

My goal is for the user to enter the type of chart and the attribute that he wants in the html form of the first page and then have the second page process the request and print the chart.

I know i posted a lot of code but ive been battling with this issue for 3 days now, any help is welcomed!

**EDIT**
I added the parts that define the `$_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] = time();` and the `$usersid`.

The problem is that i cant seem to find a way to get the data from the form and use them to create the graph. When i create the

```
<?php 
$sql = "SELECT Patient_name, count(*) as number FROM patients JOIN MSR ON patients.Patient_id = MSR.NDSnum WHERE Doctor_ID = '$usersid' GROUP BY Patient_name";
$result = $pdo->query($sql);
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
while($row = $result->fetch()){
// $array[] = $row;
   echo "['".$row['Patient_name']."',".$row['number']."],";
}?>
```

tag inside of the drawChart() function my whole `getData.php` page goes completely white. I know this is not a good way of explaining my problem, but im trying my best. Please ask me for any explanation you need.

**EDIT No.2**

After the changes from @Professor Abronsius answer, i am able to print a pie chart, unfortunately it looks like this:[image]

When i try to look at the network trafic to figure out what the json file looks like, the file looks fine:

```
0   Object { name: "Name1", number: "1" }
1   Object { name: "Name2", number: "1" }
2   Object { name: "Name3", number: "1" }
3   Object { name: "Name4", number: "1" }
4   Object { name: "Name5", number: "1" }
5   Object { name: "name6", number: "1" }
6   Object { name: "Name7", number: "1" }
7   Object { name: "Name8", number: "1" }
```

Which means that there should be printed a pieChart with equal parts of the pie.. any ideas?

**Edit 3**

There are no errors in the console when the chart gets generated, and after adding the **console.log()** at the lines:

```
Object.keys( json ).forEach(key=>{
                console.log(dataTbl.addRow( [ json[ key ].name, json[ key ].number ] ));
                
            })
```

the output in the console is the following (which i dont understand if its right or wrong):

```
Object { cq: null, bf: (2) […], Wf: (1) […], Br: null, cache: [], version: "0.6" }
​
Br: null
​
Wf: Array(8) [ {…}, {…}, {…}, … ]
​​
0: Object { c: (2) […] }
​​​
c: Array [ {…}, {…} ]
​​​​
0: Object { v: "Athanasia Moutlia" }
​​​​
1: Object { v: "1" }
​​​​
length: 2
​​​​
<prototype>: Array []
​​​
<prototype>: Object { … }
​​
1: Object { c: (2) […] }
​​
2: Object { c: (2) […] }
​​
3: Object { c: (2) […] }
​​
4: Object { c: (2) […] }
​​
5: Object { c: (2) […] }
​​
6: Object { c: (2) […] }
​​
7: Object { c: (2) […] }
​​
length: 8
​​
<prototype>: Array []
​
bf: Array [ {…}, {…} ]
​
cache: Array(8) [ (2) […], (2) […], (2) […], … ]
​
cq: null
​
version: "0.6"
​
<prototype>: Object { constructor: gvjs_M(a, b), ca: ca(), "$": $()
, … }
visual_analytics_google.php:203:13
Object { cq: null, bf: (2) […], Wf: (2) […], Br: null, cache: [], version: "0.6" }
visual_analytics_google.php:203:13
Object { cq: null, bf: (2) […], Wf: (3) […], Br: null, cache: [], version: "0.6" }
visual_analytics_google.php:203:13
Object { cq: null, bf: (2) […], Wf: (4) […], Br: null, cache: [], version: "0.6" }
visual_analytics_google.php:203:13
Object { cq: null, bf: (2) […], Wf: (5) […], Br: null, cache: [], version: "0.6" }
visual_analytics_google.php:203:13
Object { cq: null, bf: (2) […], Wf: (6) […], Br: null, cache: [], version: "0.6" }
visual_analytics_google.php:203:13
Object { cq: null, bf: (2) […], Wf: (7) […], Br: null, cache: [], version: "0.6" }
visual_analytics_google.php:203:13
Object { cq: null, bf: (2) […], Wf: (8) […], Br: null, cache: [], version: "0.6" }
visual_analytics_google.php:203:13
```

inside the layers : wf->0->c && cache i can see the data that i am expecting to populate the dataTbl, but i have no idea what is the rest of it...

Thank you in advance!

PasteBin [link](https://pastebin.com/MZz2d4P1) for `getData.php` file

PasteBin [link](https://pastebin.com/08aZL7wp) for `html-form.php` file

Comment: **Firstly** There is a mismatch between the number of opening curly braces and closing in that last piece of PHP. **Secondly** There is no `session_start()` before calling `$_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] = time();` **Thirdly** Why separate this into 2 separate pages/scripts and not use AJAX to fetch the data? **Fourth** Where is `$userid` defined being called? The same for other PHP variables in that last piece of PHP code. **Fifth** Your code is potentially vulnerable to SQL injection

Comment: What exactly is the problem here - does this not work? Does it throw errors? Please clarify  what your question is

Comment: The missmatch of braces and both the `session_start()` as well as the `$_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] = time()` exist in my code, but i removed them in the post. If you deem it necessary i will post them. This is not the problem im having. My problem is that if i hardcode the data (like the comments) the chart prints normaly. All i want to do is have the html form set both the type of chart and the attribute to appear on the chart, and with the press of the submit button generate and create a chart. As of now, if i input a `<?php ...?>` tag inside of the drawChart() js func the page turns white.

Comment: I would suggest using ajax to fetch data from a simple PHP script that runs whatever SQL query is appropriate for the selection made by the user and use the ajax callback to run the `drawChart` which could be rewritten to accept a single argument (ie: the JSON response data from db query )

Comment: I have a few questions about that approach. Firstly, where would my forms' action field point to? the `getData.php` with the simple sql queries or in the same file with the chart? And second question, what would that ajax callback look like? because what i already used (from googles' documentation) returned me `<empty string>` if i had the `async: false` and when i made the `async: true` it returned undefined...  the ajax that i used : `var jsonData = $.ajax({url: "getData.php",dataType: "json",async: false}).responseText;`

Comment: If you used Ajax you would not need the form action - you would send the http request via ajax( to a modified getData.php  perhaps or even the same page )... I'll try to show you what I mean

Comment: I've looked at the latest versions of your code and it all looks OK as far as I can see. Like you I do not know what a lot of the output from the console is. One thing, related to a previous comment you made is in regards to the column types used in the dataTable... The 2nd should be a `number` column rather than `string` - you might have to use `parseFloat` or `parseInt` when adding the numeric value to the dataTbl variable

Comment: could it be a problem with my SQL query?

Comment: WOAH! once i finally managed to add the `parseFloat` it worked fine! Thank you SO SO much!

Comment: '-) glad that I was able to offer guidance and that you have sorted your app. Good luck

Comment: What's an MSR?  A patient can have several of them?  And that is what you are graphing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of what follows is tested at all but might help you come to a solution. Rather than submit the form in a conventional manner I'd suggest separating the `getData.php` and your HTML/javascript completely. `getData.php` should just run SQL queries and send data back to the ajax callback which, in turn, calls `drawChart` to actually build the chart.

### getData.php

```
<?php

    session_start();
    error_reporting( E_ALL );
    
    if( !isset( $_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] ) or ( isset( $_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] ) && ( time() - $_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] > 18000 ) ) ) {
        session_unset();
        session_destroy();
        exit( header('Location: ?timeout=true') );
    } 
    $_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] = time();
    
    
    
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && isset(
        $_POST['attributes'],
        $_POST['charts']
    )){
        $pdo = new PDO( "mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password );
        $pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
        
        $args=array(); # default, empty array if there are no placeholders
        $attributes = $_POST['attributes'];
        $charts = $_POST['charts'];
        
        /*
            create suitable SQL statement and $args array
            for each $attribute that you wish to plot on a chart.
            
            Use a Prepared statement to mitigate SQL injection attacks.
        */
        switch( $attributes ){
            case 'Patient_name':
                $sql='SELECT Patient_name, count(*) as number 
                          FROM patients JOIN MSR ON patients.Patient_id = MSR.NDSnum 
                          WHERE Doctor_ID = :userid
                          GROUP BY Patient_name';
                $args=array(
                    ':userid'   =>  $userid
                );
            break;
            
            
            /*
                test cases...
            */
            case 'maps':
                $sql='select `county` as `name`, count(*) as `number` from `vwmaps`
                        group by `county`';
            break;
            case 'fish':
                $sql='select `family` as `name`, count(*) as `number` from `vwfishspecies`
                        group by `species_order_id`';
            break;
            
            /*
                etc etc
            */
        }
        
        if( isset( $sql, $args ) ){
            $stmt=$pdo->prepare( $sql );
            if( $stmt ) {
                $stmt->execute( $args );
            
                http_response_code( 200 );
                exit( json_encode( $stmt->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_OBJ ) ) );
            }
            exit( http_response_code( 400 ) );
        }
        
        # no sql to run...
        http_response_code( 400 );
    }
    
    # only allow POST requests
    http_response_code( 404 );

?>
```

And the `slim` version of the HTML page with no external libraries or css for demo only:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title></title>
        <style>
            #chart_div h3 span{color:red}
        </style>
        <script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
        <script>
            google.load('visualization', '1.0', { 'packages':['corechart'] });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <form name='chart-options' method='POST'>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th>Type of Chart</th>
            <td colspan='3'>
              <select name='charts'>
                <option selected hidden disabled>Please select
                <option value='Pie_chart'>Pie chart
                <option value='Bar_chart'>Bar chart
                <option value='Col_chart'>Column chart
                <option value='Area_chart'>Area
                <option value='Line_chart'>Line chart
                <option value='Scatter'>Scatter Chart
                <option value='Histogram'>Histogram Chart
              </select>
            </td>
            <th>Select an Attribute</th>
            <td colspan='3'>
              <select name='attributes'>
                <option selected hidden disabled>Please select

                <!-- test values -->
                <optgroup label='Development Tests'>
                    <option value='maps'>Map
                    <option value='fish'>Fish Species
                </optgroup>
                
                <optgroup label='Basic patient details'>
                    <option value='Patient_name'>Name
                    <option value='Patient_id'>ID
                    <option value='Sex'>Sex
                    <option value='Race'>Race
                    <option value='Age'>Age
                    <option value='Email'>Email
                    <option value='Phonenum'>Phone Number
                    <option value='smoker'>Smoker
                    <option value='Pregnant'>Pregnant
                </optgroup>
                
                <optgroup label='Extended details'>
                    <option value='Comorbidities'>Comorbidities
                    <option value='eddsscore'>EDSS Score
                    <option value='onsetsymptoms'>Onset Symptoms
                    <option value='Onsetlocalisation'>Onset Localisation
                    <option value='MRIenhancing'>MRI Enhanced Lesions
                    <option value='MRInum'>MRI Enhanced Lesions Number
                    <option value='MRIonsetlocalisation'>MRI Onset Localisation             
                </optgroup>

              </select>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        
        <button name='create' type='button' value='Create Graph'>Create Graph</button>
      </form>
      
      
      
      <div id="chart_div"></div>
      
      
      
      <script>
        
        const q=(e,n=document)=>n.querySelector(e);
        
        const getchart=(type)=>{
            let container=q('#chart_div');
            switch( type ){
                case 'Pie_chart':return new google.visualization.PieChart( container );
                case 'Bar_chart':return new google.visualization.BarChart( container );
                case 'Col_chart':return new google.visualization.ColumnChart( container );
                case 'Area_chart':return new google.visualization.AreaChart( container );
                case 'Line_chart':return new google.visualization.LineChart( container );
                case 'Scatter':return new google.visualization.ScatterChart( container );
                case 'Histogram':return new google.visualization.Histogram( container );
                default: return false;
            }           
        };
        
        const drawChart=( json, type, attr )=>{
            
            let dataTbl=new google.visualization.DataTable();
                dataTbl.addColumn( 'string', 'Name' );
                dataTbl.addColumn( 'number', 'Quantity' );
                
            Object.keys( json ).forEach( key => {
                /*
                    Now as long as the json data has 2 columns
                    you no longer need name the sql values as `name` & `number`
                    in the query as this will find & use whatever name (within reason)
                    has been assigned. 
                */
                let obj=json[ key ];
                let [ param, value ]=Object.keys( obj );
                dataTbl.addRow( [ obj[ param ], obj[ value ] ] );
            })
                
            let args={
                'title':attr,
                'width':800,
                'height':600,
                is3D:true,
                curveType:'function' 
            };
            let chart=getchart( type );
            if( chart ) chart.draw( dataTbl, args );
            else alert('Error loading Chart');
        }
        
        
        q('button[name="create"]').addEventListener('click',e=>{
            let fd=new FormData( q('form[name="chart-options"]') );
            let type=q('select[name="charts"]').value;
            let attr=q('select[name="attributes"]').options[q('select[name="attributes"]').options.selectedIndex].text;
            
            fetch( 'getData.php', { method:'post', body:fd } )
                .then( r=>r.json() )
                .then( json=>{
                    drawChart( json, type, attr);
                })
                .catch( err=>{
                    q('#chart_div').innerHTML=`<h3>Error: Failed to return data for <span>${attr}</span></h3>`
                })
        })
      </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

With minor changes made and test page built, running the app yielded:

[image: PieChart]
[image: Column Chart]
[image: Bar Chart]

Comment: thank you for the time you dedicated on this, i will start testing it right away and will get back to you!

Comment: there are likely to be a few minor errors as it is untested but the idea is ok

Comment: I have one question. I am bumping into the error `Uncaught (in promise) Error: Column header row must be an array.` I assume that it has to do with the json file that is returned from the `getData.php` ? But i cant understand where this json array is being compiled.

Comment: Since posting as an answer I knocked up a test page using 2 queries pertinent to one of my databases. I found a few errors in original version - one of which related to the json data being returned, another was the lack of the chart container being supplied as an argument to the chart constructor. Also `ColChart` was invalid - should have been `ColumnChart`

Comment: I am thankfull for all the time you have put into solving my problem and im trully thankful since ive been strugling a long time. There are still a few small kinks that i think i will be able to iron out myself. When i eventually do, i will accept your answer!
thank you very much !

Comment: glad to help - let me know if you need assistance "ironing out the kinks"

Comment: I made an edit to my question regarding the problem im facing, any ideas?

Comment: You need to debug within the `drawChart` or the ajax callback. For instance, is the dataTbl being populated correctly in the loop? Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: There are no errors in the console, and the `console.log(dataTbl)` prints the  "chaos" that i included in my most recent edit...  all that stuff look way too advanced for me and i have to admit, im really lost.

Comment: What changes have you made to the PHP in `getData.php`? Also, what changes have you made to the `drawChart` and the `fetch` callback?

Comment: at the `getData.php` file i made little to none changes. In the `drawChart()` i change the `dataTbl.addColumn('number', 'Number');` with the `dataTbl.addColumn('string', 'Number');` because it interfered with my data and nothing else, apart from the `console.log()` in an effort to debug... in the `fetch()` i didnt change anything. should i?

Comment: perhaps add the code to a [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/) paste and let me know the details ( though I have to now go to hospital so it'll be some time before I can respond )

Comment: no problem, i will try to make a pastebin, i hope everything goes ok. I will wait for your post.